# Is the StorageLevel 'MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER' deprecated in Spark 3.0?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am changing my pyspark project from 2.4 version to 3.0, and when I ran my code, I get the error below. More in detail, I am passing from AWS Glue 2.0 to 4.0

```
df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
```

I got the Error

```
Type object 'StorageLevel' has no attribute 'MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER'
```

I tried to find some similar error/documentation but I couldn't find.
Anyone knows if it was deprecated? Which will be the best replacement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The docs suggest that since records will always be serialized in Python, it has been removed. Just use MEMORY_AND_DISK

Compare for example 2.1.2 documentation (SERs are available):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.StorageLevel

to 3.0

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=storagelevel#pyspark.StorageLevel

source code states:

.. note:: The following four storage level constants are deprecated in 2.0, since the records 
will always be serialized in Python.
"""
StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER = StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY
""".. note:: Deprecated in 2.0, use `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY` instead."""
StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2 = StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_2
""".. note:: Deprecated in 2.0, use `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_2` instead."""
StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK
""".. note:: Deprecated in 2.0, use `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK` instead."""
StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2 = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2
""".. note:: Deprecated in 2.0, use `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2` instead."""

see class StorageLevel from source code of 3.0 : https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/storagelevel.html#StorageLevel